# How to done payment option through inapp

Tags: iphone

I have done a bible application in iphone,there is a last section called database download,there are 10 buttons each buttons have diffrent language database to download,the database is bible database,if the user tap the hebrew button it will have to download the hebrew database from the server through Inapp.I know there is no other direct payment option available in ios,but we can use the store kit framework for acesses the inapp purchase.But i didnt know how to do this.If anyone have an idea for doing a inapp payment purchase and download within the app,please share with me,it will be a great help for me to do this.
Thanks regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't handle the download through StoreKit (the framework for performing in-app purchases). You do that yourself, however you'd like.

One you download it, it'll need to be stored in the app's Documents folder.

Use this for performing the financial transaction:
https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit

Comment: sir,can i implement this for payment option?only completing the payment option i need to download the dbase.is trhat possible?

Comment: Yes, you'll get a notification in code when the payment completes, then you should download the database.